# How to select a row for certain (or give preference in the selection) in mysql?

Tags: sql, mysql, ranking, rank

Need your help guys in forming a query.

Example.
Company - Car Rental

Table - Cars

```
ID  NAME       STATUS
1   Mercedes   Showroom
2   Mercedes   On-Road
```

Now, how do I select only one entry from this table which satisfies the below conditions?

1. If Mercedes is available in Showroom, then fetch only that row. (i.e. row 1 in above example)
2. But If none of the Mercedes are available in the showroom, then fetch any one of the rows. (i.e. row 1 or row 2) - (This is just to say that all the mercedes are on-road)

Using distinct ain't helping here as the ID's are also fetched in the select statement

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have ranking/analytic/windowing functions, but you can use a variable to simulate ROW_NUMBER functionality (when you see "--", it's a comment):

```
SELECT x.id, x.name, x.status
  FROM (SELECT t.id,
               t.name,
               t.status,
               CASE 
                 WHEN @car_name != t.name THEN @rownum := 1 -- reset on diff name
                 ELSE @rownum := @rownum + 1 
               END AS rank,
               @car_name := t.name -- necessary to set @car_name for the comparison
          FROM CARS t 
          JOIN (SELECT @rownum := NULL, @car_name := '') r
      ORDER BY t.name, t.status DESC) x  --ORDER BY is necessary for rank value
 WHERE x.rank = 1
```

Ordering by status DESC means that "Showroom" will be at the top of the list, so it'll be ranked as 1.  If the car name doesn't have a "Showroom" status, the row ranked as 1 will be whatever status comes after "Showroom".  The WHERE clause will only return the first row for each car in the table.

The status being a text based data type tells me your data is not normalized - I could add records with "Showroom", "SHOWroom", and "showROOM".  They'd be valid, but you're looking at using functions like LOWER & UPPER when you are grouping things for counting, sum, etc.  The use of functions would also render an index on the column useless...  You'll want to consider making a CAR_STATUS_TYPE_CODE table, and use a foreign key relationship to make sure bad data doesn't get into your table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `example`.`car_status_type_code`;
CREATE TABLE  `example`.`car_status_type_code` (
  `car_status_type_code_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `description` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`car_status_type_code_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! That's exactly what I wanted.

Actually, the statuses are int columns in my DB. But while providing an example here I gave it as text. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a common way of solving that problem:

```
SELECT *,
CASE STATUS
WHEN 'Showroom' THEN 0
ELSE 1
END AS InShowRoom
FROM Cars
WHERE NAME = 'Mercedes'
ORDER BY InShowRoom
LIMIT 1
```

---

Here's how to get all the cars, which also shows another way to solve the problem:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, IFNULL(c2.STATUS, c1.STATUS)
FROM Cars c1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Cars c2
ON c2.NAME = c1.NAME AND c2.STATUS = 'Showroom'
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY NAME
```

Comment: Thanks Marcus. Nice trick indeed! :-) Is it possible to generalize it?  i.e. When the Cars table has other cars as well and if there are more than two rows for the same car.

Comment: Okay....Combining your logic, I will try to see if the current row being fetched has not been fetched already. That should solve it I guess. 

Edit : But the query might take a long time when there are numerous records in the table.

Comment: @rocksolid, I've edited my answer to show how to return rows for all the cars using the same conditions. This could also be performed with a sub query, but I like JOINs better.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. But have decided to go ahead with the solution given by OMG Ponies

Comment: Not everyone likes simple, I suppose.

Comment: :-) Nothing like that. Yours might be equally good or maybe better. But, I found the other solution pretty easy to digest eventhough it might look complex.

Answer (score 3):

You would want to use the [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_find_in_set.asp) function to do that.

```
SELECT *
FROM Cars
WHERE NAME = 'Mercedes'
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(`STATUS`,'Showroom') DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If you have a preferred order of other statuses, just add them to the second parameter.

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(`STATUS`,'On-Road,Showroom' ) DESC
```

To fetch 'best' status for all cars you can simply do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Cars
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(`STATUS`,'Showroom') DESC
```

Comment: When using FIND_IN_SET() with multiple items in the string list, note that since you're using `DESC` for the order, you'd want to put your preferred items in descending order in the string list.

Comment: Thanks mate. Will check this out. But how do we write it in a general manner? Cars table with other cars as well?

Comment: Not quite sure if i follow you there. The `ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET()` is just a way to order elements in a non-numerical and non-alphabetic order, but rather a user defined order. The rest of the query could be handled like any other queries with joins and subselects.

Comment: Okay...What I meant was that, how do we use this query without the WHERE clause? (If there are other cars in the table).

Comment: @rocksolid Added another simple query to fetch a car with the desired status (if available) for all cars in the table

Comment: Using FIND_IN_SET in the order by will still return more record per car name, they'll just be further down the list

Comment: @OMG Ponies There's a `GROUP BY NAME` in there to prevent any duplicate car names from showing up.

Comment: Sorry, missed that though I still loath to rely on MySQL's non-standard behavior of omitting columns from the GROUP BY.  There are few if any databases the query would port to.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM cars 
  WHERE name = 'Mercedes' 
  AND status = 'Showroom' 
UNION SELECT * FROM cars 
  WHERE name = 'Mercedes' 
LIMIT 1;
```

**EDIT** Removed the ALL on the UNION since we only want distinct rows anyway.

Comment: By default `UNION` returns an unordered set of rows. Therefore, you should use `UNION ALL` so that MySQL keeps the order. However, I don't know if this can be relied upon. It is probably best to specify an order using `ORDER BY`.